# Tamir SharpSSh get method getting wrong modification date as compared to sftp server

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, sharpssh

I am using SharpSSH.SFTP(TAmir) library to get the file using Get() method from a ftp server using sftp protocol.
I am able to successfully fetch the file from the server but its having the timestamp of when the file was fetched,not the original timestamp(i.e of ftp server).
Is there any work around to get modification date along with file?

Thanks,
GT